# Rails, abilities with cancancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, block, roles, cancan, cancancan

I am using cancancan to define abilities for my demo restaurant app. Each restaurant has_many employees and each employee has **user_id** and **role** attributes. I would like to allow a user to edit a restaurant **only if** this restaurant has an employee with user_id as the current_user.id and his role is 'manager'. My problem is that this role could be given to a lot of employees and when I find them by

```
can :edit, Restaurant do |restaurant|
    restaurant.employees.where(role: 'Manager').id=user.id 
end
```

I would get an array of all managers and this code would not return true. Any ideas of how to implement this :? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for something more like this:

```
can :edit, Restaurant do |restaurant|
  restaurant.employees.where(role: 'Manager', user_id: user.id).exists?
end
```